# Equivalent of packages.ubuntu.com on Fedora

Tags: ubuntu, debian, fedora

I'm new to Fedora and I would like to know if there is an equivalent of `packages.ubuntu.com` for Fedora? It's very convenient to search a package by name or file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is PKGDB:

https://admin.fedoraproject.org/pkgdb/

In the detail of the package you can find everything related to the package, including source code, patches, bugs, builds, updates, whatever you can think of:

https://admin.fedoraproject.org/pkgdb/package/rpms/openssh/

To search for files, it is more convenient to use DNF from command line:

```
dnf provides /path/to/file
```

Answer (score 3):

[pkgdb](https://admin.fedoraproject.org/pkgdb/) is our *administrative* interface to the package database. But we actually also have a completely separate [Fedora Packages Search](https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/). This has an interface that's probably more useful for most end-users (and sometimes for contributors too).

Comment: This is a nice search engine. But you can't search on file name, can you?

Comment: That's true — but you can't from the pkgdb either. Jakuje's suggestion of using the dnf command line is a good one for that case.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning this one. The both sites are backlinked so you can get from one to the other and vice versa. I am actually using the Packages Search myself, but I somehow use pkgdb as the landing page, so it came to my mind first.